# Azure Application Gateway how to dynamically redirect based on table-data

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

In a sharding configuration across multiple Azure-VMs (Linux), each with its own sub-domain (wildcard *.domain.com Azure dns-zone), the gateway must parses the SUB-DOMAIN-NAME.domain.com connect attempt and access a remote Azure Table-Storage (or any other REST endpoint) to determine which target Azure-VM to use for this. This Azure-VM determined will then be used for the remainder of the sticky-session (affinity cookie).

This should be possible via PowerShell configuration, but current limitations seem to exist as described here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/881988/azure-application-gateway-limitations-wildcard-ssl-cert

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/19527121-application-gateway-support-wildcard-hosts-in-lis

Any tips on support for this scenario within the Azure Application Gateway or do I need to look elsewhere?

Secondary question but also necessary for this scenario: access to an Azure-table-storage from the Azure Application Gateway PowerShell possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cant have wildcard listener in an Azure Application Gateway, but you can have a generic listener, which will route all traffic to some endpoint, so your listeners can be something like this:

   - hostA.domain.com > host1
   - hostB.domain.com > host2
   - hostA.example.com > host3
   - hostB.example.com > host4
     ...
   - everything that doesnt match the above hostnames goes to this last listener > hostx
2. there is no Azure Application Gateway PowerShell, you just have Azure Application Gateway module in PowerShell, so you can use anything you can regularly use in PowerShell along with Azure Application Gateway cmdlets. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#query-the-table-entities) an example of how to query Azure Table storage in PowerShell.

Comment: Appreciated. Your  item 1. needs to be dynamic though (runtime): every time a new hostX appears on one of the hostN, then a new entry must also appear in the listeners list as hostXsub.domain.com > hostN-VM. Possible? Same applies for item 2. PowerShell used for a pre-configuring is not adequate for this scenario, I need the PowerShell intepreter at runtime to query the Table-Store since the table is continually growing with new hostXsubdomain > hostN-VM entries. I hope I'm still missing something?

Comment: 1. no, you need to create a script to do that 2. i dont understand the question. you can run powershell script at anytime to do that. but keep in mind you are limited to 40 listeners per application gateway.

Comment: Thanks. OK, updating the whole configuration (via PS) each time a new subdomain appears is not feasible (seconds) and the limit of 40 is the real show stopper (thousands). It would be so easy to support this scenario. Elas, too bad I can't use the application gateway. Thanks for clarity here.